# "Sameness" of dg and A-infinity categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, sg.symplectic-geometry, higher-category-theory

Let $k$ be a field.

A folklore theorem states that dg-categories (over $k$), $A_{\infty}$-categories (over $k$) and stable ($k$-linear) $(\infty, 1)$-categories are "the same"  (see for example
[Stable infinity categories vs dg-categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114251/stable-infinity-categories-vs-dg-categories)).

I would like to understand in what sense (and why) dg- and $A_{\infty}$-categories are "the same".

There is a canonical inclusion functor from the category of dg categories to the category of $A_{\infty}$ categories. However, this functor is not full, so it does not define an equivalence of categories.

Comment: Any $A_\infty$-algebra is quasiequivalent to a dg-algebra through the cobar-bar construction.

Comment: Ah, so perhaps the equivalence of categories I'm looking for sends an $A_{\infty}$ algebra $A$ to the dg algebra $\Omega B A$. I need to think a bit more, but I think this answers the question at the level of algebras.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By Corollary 9.2.1 in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5675
the model category of small A_∞-categories
is Quillen equivalent to the model category of small categories
(with a fixed set of objects for simplicity, but see
also Proposition 9.2.3 for the general case),
where both types of categories are enriched over a fixed monoidal tractable model category,
such as chain complexes over a commutative ring,
simplicial sets,
simplicial modules over a commutative ring,
symmetric spectra, etc.

The proof there also gives explicit formulas for the rectification operation.

Comment: Could you please clarify how Corollary 9.2.1. relates to dg-categories?  (I apologize if this is obvious -- I have very little background in this area).

Comment: @user142700: If C=V=Ch, then algebras over the operad Cat^O_W are A_∞-dg-categories respectively dg-categories if O=A_∞ respectively As (the associative operad) with W as a set of objects.

Comment: But A_infinity categories don't have a model structure!

Comment: @FrancescoGenovese they do.

Comment: @FrancescoGenovese: The easiest way to construct a model structure on A_∞-categories is to fix a set of objects first.  A_∞-categories with a fixed set of objects are algebras over a certain nonsymmetric colored operad, and algebras over nonsymmetric colored operads in chain complexes or simplicial sets always admit a transferred model structure (see Fernando Muro's paper Homotopy theory of nonsymmetric operads, and its errata).

Comment: @DmitriPavlov no, and the reason is that A_infty categories are not complete/cocomplete. Check §1.5 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.07830.pdf If you say that there is some "variant" of this, then maybe... but definitely not according to the usual definition

Comment: @FrancescoGenovese: The paper you referenced is talking about a very different category, the category of A_∞-categories and A_∞-functors (not ordinary enriched functors) between them.  As far as I am aware, we don't know how to define A_∞-functors for arbitrary A_∞-operads in arbitrary monoidal model categories, which is the context of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best answer so far comes from this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.07830 , where it is proved that homotopy categories of dg-categories and various flavours of A-infinity categories are equivalent.